# How to display html file in jeditorepane after doc to html conversion?

Tags: java, swing, file, jeditorpane

I converted a doc file to html and displayed that doc file on my jeditorepane .

This program is working on my admin account. When I login in with a user account in my windows xp  that file is not displayed.

```
try
{

               File docFile=new File("c:\\159.doc");   // file object was created
             FileInputStream finStream=new FileInputStream(docFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
             HWPFDocument doc=new HWPFDocument(finStream);

       WordExtractor wordExtract=new WordExtractor(doc);
         Document newDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(newDocument) ;

    wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(doc);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8" );
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "html" );
    transformer.transform(
            new DOMSource( wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument() ),
            new StreamResult( stringWriter ) );

    String html = stringWriter.toString();

          System.out.println(html);


        FileOutputStream fos; 
            DataOutputStream dos;

           File file= new File("C:\\my.html");
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
     // dos.writeInt();
      dos.writeUTF(html);

     JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
     editorPane.setEditable(false);


            editorPane.setPage(file.toURL());

           JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);     

               JFrame f = new JFrame("O'Reilly & Associates");
     // Next line requires Java 1.3
                  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
                f.setSize(512, 342);
                f.setVisible(true);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: First take a look at this [how do I write a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) for writing a string, which is already in your HTML format, as this will create a binary file for you. You will understand this when you open `C:\\my.html` in notepad. It won't look like your regular HTML file and is most likely to start with an unprintable character, instead of `<HTML>` tag.

Instead you can use a simple [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
File file= new File("C:\\my.html");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
fw.write(html);
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

**EDIT :**

Also it is recommended to use `file.toURI().toURL()` instead of `file.toURL()` as the latter is a deprecated method. According to java docs

> This method does not automatically escape characters that are illegal
>   in URLs. It is recommended that new code convert an abstract pathname
>   into a URL by first converting it into a URI, via the toURI method,
>   and then converting the URI into a URL via the URI.toURL method.